# Rxjs map() function's parameter is null

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7

I have the following `INterceptor` in `Angular`.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    //handle response
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        tap(evt => {
            if (evt instanceof HttpResponse) {
                if (evt.status == 201) {
                    this.toastrService.success('Successfully Created', 
                    'Success', this.toastConfig);
                } 
                if (evt.status == 202) {
                    this.toastrService.success('Successfully Updated', 
                    'Success', this.toastConfig);
                } 
                if (evt.status == 204) {
                    this.toastrService.success('Successfully Deleted', 
                    'Success', this.toastConfig);
                } 
            }
            return of(evt);
        }),
        catchError((err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                if (err.status == 401) {
                    let strMessage = err.error ? err.error.Message ? err.error.Message : "Authorization Error: You are not allowed to access the requested resource" :  "Authorization Error: You are not allowed to access the requested resource";
                    this.toastrService.warning(strMessage, "Authentication Response", this.toastConfig);
                } else if (err.status == 500) {
                    this.toastrService.error("Oops! Somethign went wrong.", "Internal Error", this.toastConfig)
                } else {
                    this.toastrService.error(err.message, "Error", this.toastConfig);
                }
            }

            return of(err);
        })
    );
}
```

Then, I have a `userService` with the following `deleteUser()` function:

```
public deleteUser(id: number): Observable<boolean> {
return this.httpClient.delete<any>(environment.endpoints.user.deleteUserById(id))
  .pipe(map(x => {
    if (x instanceof HttpResponse) {
      return x.status == 204 ? true : false;
    }
  }))
```

}

I execute the `deleteUser()` function by `subscribing` to it as follow from within a component:

```
deleteEvent(id: number): void {
    this.userService.deleteUser(id)
       .subscribe(x => {
        if (x) {
           this.search(); //refreshes list
        }
      });
  }
```

My problem is, the `.pipe(map(x => {...}` x parameter is null.

I am returning the `HttpResponse` from the `Interceptor`, but there is no response received in my `userService` in the `map()`.

Comment: I supouse `.pipe(map(x => {  return (x instanceof HttpResponse && x.status==204)?true:false    }))`

Comment: @mbojko Thanks.  I completely forgot to tell Angular that I want the full response with { observe: 'response' }

Answer (score -1):

I think your issue is that you return within `tap` operator.

As far as I remember, `tap` always returns `void` and this could be an issue, no?

Comment: The `return of(evt);` won't do anything, but the next operator/subscriber in the pipe will get the unaltered stream anyway.

Comment: No. I needed to add { observe: 'response' } to my http calls options to tell Angular that I want the full HttpResponse object back

Comment: tap does not return void, it just listens to the stream and does not modify it at all